# Can I make a second board a sub-board of another?

Tags: trello, trello-boards

Can I make another board a sub-board of an existing one?

It's purely because I am doing other school projects as well so I would like to have all of them in their respective subjects (one board is not enough for a subject).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add sub-board. You can `Add List` inside a board as a sub-board.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to create sub-boards in Trello with the Chrome extension [Nests for Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nests-for-trello/eibnacdidooamhebiehhlafljlipplmd). Have not used it myself though.